# Block Microsoft SharePoint Mobile App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, mobile

I need to block my users' access to the SharePoint Online site from the 'Microsoft SharePoint' mobile app. Or at least hide everything on it?

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please go through this link might be help you.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-up-and-manage-mobile-access-for-your-users-01fff219-4492-40f2-82d3-fd2ffc0ad802

Comment: Is there a solution for this? I have created our SharepPoint site it's access to documents based on view permissions. These permissions do not apply on the SharePoint mobile app and OneDrive so this renders all the work futile. Somebody with some advice to handle this? Hoping for a disbable of the mobile app feature or same view possibilities as for SharePoint online! Michael

Comment: Hi @Michael, I've ended up setting up a Conditional Access Policy on Azure AD, which blocks users access to SharePoint App from iOS, Android and Windows phone platforms - forcing them to use the desktop version. However, this Conditional Access Policy also blocks their access to OneDrive app on mobile, and there's no way to block just one of these apps without blocking the other at the moment (contacted MS Support)...

Comment: Hi Gintas, did you got the solution? How to block this app?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this article :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/control-access-to-features-in-the-onedrive-and-sharepoint-mobile-apps-d25713bb-5cf8-4874-9b5b-e8bee3b94f13

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no settings to block the app there. Working on this with MS Support at the moment, the only way to do this is setting up the conditional access policy on MS Intune... Tried it, but that didn't work either! Will keep this post updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to Block access:

1. Go to Access control in the new SharePoint admin center, and sign in with an account that has admin permissions for your organization.
2. Select Unmanaged devices.
3. Select Block access, and then select Save.

Hope This Works.